# Java web app not responding to HTTP requests when deployed to Azure App Service using Windows app service plan

Tags: java, azure, azure-deployment

I have built a web app which runs with simply `java -jar app.jar`. It looks at the environment variable `PORT` to decide which port to listen on. now I want to deploy it to Azure with a Windows app service plan, this is called This is called "Java SE deployment" in Azure.

On a Linux app service plan, I can simply deploy the app.jar file (using vs code plugin, zipdeploy, or whatever), set the environment variable PORT, and everything is fine.

With a Windows app service plan, attempting to access the app gives a 500 error with the body "The web server failed to respond within the specified time". I've turned on all the logging I can, and I can see the request gets into IIS but no indication that it's attempted to send the request to my app.

However I can access my app directly from the Azure console using `curl http://localhost:<port>`. so I know it has started up.

I've done this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-java?tabs=javase&pivots=platform-windows which works fine, but I'm not using maven or spring boot - I need to build the jar file myself.

I've read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-java?pivots=platform-windows but they doesn't seem to be telling me anything I don't already know.

Comment: localhost could indicate your program is listening on 127.0.0.1 ip which is not accessible from anything other than localhost. Perhaps you need to bind it to public/lan ip?

Comment: @wowbagger as I understand it, when you use the "Java SE" type of deployment, your app listens on a local port, and azure proxies the incoming requests to it. That's how it works on Linux app service anyhow

Comment: I don’t know Azure but don’t you need to open it up like a firewall rule or similar?

Comment: no - the whole point of the web app PAAS is that Azure handles everything to do with proxy, SSL, load balancing etc. and the app is running inside a sandbox

Comment: You still need to configure it, if it would just forward "any port your app has openend" you potentially end up opening ports you don't want to be publicly available. Good to hear you sorted it out!

Answer (score 2):

By dumping out the environment in my app, I discovered that Azure sets the environment variable SERVER_PORT to a number and that if you listen on that number, the requests are forwarded correctly. It actually sets quite a few environment variables to the same port number, but I chose SERVER_PORT because it looks like the most meaningful name, and there are some references to it in various blogs etc. HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT is also set.

I'd still be grateful for any references to official Microsoft documentation, so at least I know whether there's a "proper" way to do this.

Comment: I just had the same issue, and only found this answer _after_ finding the SERVER_PORT variable myself. :P I edited your question-title to hopefully make it more discoverable.

Comment: it might be that you can set SERVER_PORT as well if you want to listen on a specific port, but I didn't test that.